# Connection Error on Console screen of Redis Cache Azure

Tags: azure, cache

On the console screen of redis cache of azure. I write any syntax to retrieve data, sometimes, i get the following error:

Connection Failure: If this issue persists, ensure your computer's firewall and proxy settings allow outbound TCP traffic to port 10225. Using the firewall feature on your cache may also block connections from the console if your IP address has not been whitelisted

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974810/207131), it's a firewall restriction. The console executes in your browser and because of this, you need to add your IP to the firewall.

Go in > Azure Cache for Redis > Firefall (Settings)
and add your machine's public IP (needs to be visible to Azure).

[image: Azure Cache Menu]

Answer (score 0):

If You are using only a private endpoint and have disabled the public access then go to the Private endpoint -> Enable Public network access and then try. It should work.
I hope this will help.